# Font not rendering T-comma (Ț) and t-comma (ț) properly

Tags: fonts, truetype, typography

I have an issue with the [Capsuula](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/capsuula) font. It's not rendering the T-comma or the t-comma characters properly, instead it defaults to a system font (Times New Roman in my case). This happens in both desktop and font-face version. I cannot use another font, as the company brand is based on it.

[image: The fallback is to a totally different font]

Is there something wrong with the character mapping or could there be something else? (several users have reported such issues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the font does not have these characters. It has the *glyphs*, but they're encoded at [U+0162](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/162/index.htm) and [U+0163](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/163/index.htm), not [U+021A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21a/index.htm) and [U+021B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21b/index.htm) where you are probably expecting them (or more likely where your keyboard driver is expecting them). What you're seeing is the result of a font fallback mechanism, trying to display *something* for the characters. It works, but it looks horrible as you've pointed out.

Ask the font developer to update the font, properly encode the glyphs at U+021A and U+021B.

Comment: Thanks @djangodude, I've notified the font developer just before posting the issue here, but still no word. I might try to look into the font myself and try to adjust the glyphs encoding.

Comment: As a last resort, you could try modifying your text to use U+0162 and U+0163 though I don't really advise this for long-term use. It will solve the problem visually, but will cause other problems.

Comment: I remapped the glyphs to the correct chars and it seems to be working fine now.